# Refresh design time datacontext in Blend

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'm using Blend 2012 and Visual Studio to design a Windows 8 app.
I'm using the MVVM Light toolkit and I'm binding my ViewModels to the page's datacontext.

On the viewmodel I use dependency injection to inject a data service into the ViewModel.
At design time I'm injecting a dummy dataservice so that I can have design time data in Blend.

This works fine. The one problem I'm struggling with is actually forcing Blend to update whenever I make a change to the dummy class. Sometimes I want to add a method or change some data and I don't know how I can tell Blend to actually recompile the dummy class and use the new methods. I have tried a rebuild of all solutions and a restart of both Visual Studio and Blend, but neither of does trigger the "design-time" build. After a while it gets updated, but I don't know what triggers it, and how I can do this manually.

¿Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround:

1. Rebuild project in Blend
2. Close document
3. Terminate the process XDesProc.exe via the task manager (make sure it's the Xaml designer from Blend not from VS)
4. Reopen the document Still, this just doesn't sound right